# Brand new installed Delphi XE freezes without reason (it is QC 90864 Delphi bug)

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I finally upgraded to Delphi XE.
The second time when I compile a project in Delphi XE, as soon as I hit the BUILD button the IDE freezes. Nothing can stop its agony except 'End Task'. What should I do? This is a fresh installation from the original CD. No single 3rd party plugin/VCL has been installed.

Edit 1: The last change I did was to remove some of the pre-installed packages such as DBs and Rave.
Edit 2: I realized the if freezes also when I use 'compile'. The last message it shows in 'Messages' is 'Checking project dependencies...'
Edit 3: It seems to be 'Background compilation'

Has anyone experienced this problem?

---

**Update:**
I just realized that this feature is useless anyway since the compile time for my program is about 2.2 seconds in normal mode and 6 seconds in background mode (high priority).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it is a 'magic' bug in Delphi.

<strike>SOLUTION

To fix the bug see: 
Delphi XE Hotfix for QC 90864</strike>

---

### UPDATE

I 'installed' the update yesterday but only today I turned back on the 'background compilation'. Guess what... it does not solve the bug!!!

Comment: You mean "this was a reported bug (QC 90864) that was fixed in a hotfix"? There's no "magic bug", or major mystery. All software has bugs; this one was fixed as it should have been.

Comment: Maybe you are right Ken. I many good hours installing and reinstalling Delphi XE and hacking the packages and the registry only to find out that it was a bug in Delphi. So, maybe you are perfectly right: the magic will only happen when I will get my time back.

Comment: Are you using old AMD CPU with ATI AGP graphic card on Windows 7?

Comment: @avra-What? The bug only appears on AMD?

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed in an update. You need to apply the current updates to XE.